# convert string to a specific class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array in a file and this is the content.

`var nameList= ['Dirk', 'Luc', 'Bea', 'Frank', 'An', 'Lieve', 'Mia', 'Marc'];`

.....................................................

There is a class in a file like this.

`class GenderData {  final String name;  GenderData({required this.name});}`

............................

if I try to use the first one in the array as an item in my statefulwidget i got the error that means I use a string instead of the GenderData class.

```
class Genderpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GenderpageState createState() => _GenderpageState();
}

class _GenderpageState extends State<Genderpage> {
  late GenderData currentName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentName = nameList[0];
  }
```

I would not like to change my array.
I used this command but it did not work too.

```
currentName = nameList[0] as GenderData;
```

Is there any way to convert a string to the class without manipulating the main array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign a string directly to a variable of a different type. You just need to create a GenderData object and assign it to the variable in case you want the variable as such.

```
currentName = GenderData(name: nameList[0]);
```

Another point worth mentioning is that if you will only store a gender's name in a class I would rather keep working with strings. Instead if you are going to use GenderData to store more properties then it is ok.